# What is the best approach; hashing password in req.body.password or at the database user.password in express-mongoose web app

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating a user post route in which i'll be doing the password hashing. So what is the best approach for hashing password is it this;

```
let user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
if (user) return res.status(400).send('The user already exists')

user = new User({
    name : req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
})


// hashing user passwords
const salting = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salting)
```

Hashing it on the database level or this;

```
let user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
if (user) return res.status(400).send('The user already exists')

 // hashing user passwords
    const salting = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salting)

user = new User({
    name : req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword
})
```

hashing on the request level, or there is a better way of doing the hashing? Your opinions/recommendation will be much useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to store username and password of a user in mongoDB is using this mongoose library: **'passport-local-mongoose'** this will add username and password fields to your schema and the password will be saved as hashed password.

it's very easy to use(in your user schema file):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose')

var userSchema = new Schema({
   admin:{
      type:Boolean,
      default:false
   },
firstName:{
    type:String,
    default:''
},
lastName:{
    type:String,
    default:''
},

})

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)

var Users = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)

module.exports = Users
```

and you can authenticate user credentials using same library with passport local strategy like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((User.authenticate())))
```